# How to set try/catch block with rollback in SQL 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, transactions, rollback

I have SQL transaction inside of the stored procedure that will run every time when customers try to Insert or Update records in Dictionary table. Originally I have used ColdFusion to handle transaction and roll back but since I moved everything in stored procedure I need SQL to take care of that now. Here is example of my ColdFusion and SQL code:

```
<cftransaction action="begin">
    <cftry>
        <cfquery name="qrySave" datasource="#dsn#">
            UPDATE Dictionary WITH (serializable)
            SET Name = Name
            WHERE pk = @id
            IF @@rowcount = 0
            BEGIN
              INSERT Dictionary (pk, Name)
              VALUES (@id,1)
            END
        </cfquery>

        <cfset local.fnResults = {status : "200", RecID : qrySave.RecID}>

        <cfcatch type="any">
            <cftransaction action="rollback" />
            <cfset local.fnResults = {status : "400"}>
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cftransaction>
```

Example above should be modified and use SQL Transaction and Rollback, I got this so far:

```
begin tran
   update Dictionary with (serializable)
   set Name = Name
   where pk = @id
   if @@rowcount = 0
   begin
      insert Dictionary (pk, Name)
      values (@id,1)
   end
commit tran
```

I still need try/catch with rollback and then put this in Stored procedure. If anyone have example on how that should look like please let me know.

Comment: `SET XACT_ABORT ON` at the beginning is sufficient to ensure the transaction does not continue and rolls back at the first error. If you need custom recovery code or you expect that stored procedures will be nested, things get a little more complicated, and I advise you to read [this](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html). Error handling in T-SQL is an intricate subject, and rather than just knowing everyone's favorite boilerplate it helps to know how it actually works.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+try+catch+rollback+example&oq=sql+server+try+catch+with+rollback&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i60j0l4.8815j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @TabAlleman great answer... Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @JeroenMostert's comment about understanding what you're doing, but I'll give you my favorite boilerplate code as a starting point just the same.

Try/Catch is valid T-SQL, starting with SQL Server 2008, so you're in luck there, though you really should consider upgrading soon, as 2008 falls out of extended support in July 2019.

My usual pattern is to initiate a transaction, initiate a `TRY` block, `COMMIT` the transaction if the code succeeds, or `ROLLBACK` in the `CATCH` block in the event of a failure, and to also return some information about the error. Here's a pretty basic implementation of that.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
  UPDATE
    Dictionary WITH (SERIALIZABLE)
  SET
    Name = Name
  WHERE
    pk = @id;
  IF @@rowcount = 0
    BEGIN;
      INSERT Dictionary (pk ,Name)
      VALUES (@id, 1);
    END;
  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
  SELECT -- As many or few of these as you care to return
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
   ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
   ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
   ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
   ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
   ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH
```

Comment: Eric, this is something that I was looking for and I'm wondering if this is a good fit for stored procedure? Also let's say that Insert or Update fails because of the error would that try catch block return all errors that you declared in catch block?

Comment: It would return information about the error that triggered the catch block. To echo Jeroen again, though, if you want to be sure this works in your situation, it's best to just use it as a starting point and then do additional research to understand the process as thoroughly as possible. But yes, I use something very close to this pattern in many of my stored procedures.

Comment: Eric, I just started using stored procedure. System that i'm developing is state wide and we expect a huge load of data. So I'm trying to develop reliable method for these transactions. Some of the things that I try to prevent are deadlocks and server blocking. I hope this approach is leading in the right direction.

Comment: If you compare this to the answer in the question that Tab linked to, you'll see that they're about the same. It's a pretty normal SQL pattern. In my previous position, I used it over and over again in support of a pretty high volume ecommerce company (up to a few thousand transactions per minute at peak times) and it served us well. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you, Eric. This will help definitely.

Comment: @EricBrandt Is a Try catch rollback even necesssary? Will a failed query not rollback on it's own as the commit is never reached?

Comment: @MichaelD, yes, the rollback is necessary. If you explicitly open a transaction with a [`BEGIN TRANSACTION`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement, that transaction stays open until you either give it an explicit `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` command. If you don't do the explicit `BEGIN`, then SQL Server manages all of that in background by default, but be aware of [`SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).